# How can I revert an .aab file to code in React native?

Tags: react-native, google-play

My computer got in an accident that wiped my hard drive, and i lost the code I've been working on for 4 months. All i have left is the .aab that i uploaded to google play store. Is there any way i can reverse or unbundle the .aab to get my code back?

I tried using bundletool but I just got confused and it seemed directed at converting to .apk which im not sure is relevant for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to extract APK from aab with `bundletool` like in instruction https://docs.catappult.io/docs/extract-your-apps-apks-from-aab-file

Second, you need to unzip APK with `apktool` - `apktool  d /pathOfApkFile.apk`

Third, you can try to decompile `index.android.bundle` using https://github.com/numandev1/react-native-decompiler